# PHP Implode not separating the array

Tags: php, html, mysql, arrays

I'm pulling in a MySQL query from a form page using $_POST.  The previous page is sending a list of IDs from the database.  However when I use implode it's echoing out a string:

2210222022362244

Even though I'm using the Implode function:

```
$variable = implode(',' ,$_POST['job_ids']);
echo $variable
```

I've also tried the variation:

```
$variable = implode(',' ,(array)$_POST['job_ids']);
echo $variable
```

However that echoes out the same string.  I've also tried a 'get' and it produced this URL string, which generated the same: '2210222022362244' string:

testing.php?job_ids%5B%5D=%0D%0A%09%09%09%09%09++%09%09%0D%0A%09%09%09%09%09++%09%092210222022362244%09%09%09%09%09++%09%09%0D%0A%09%09%09%09%09++%09%09&supervisorid=58

The output I'm looking for is:

2210,2220,2236,2244

I'm wanting to store those values in a variable and then use them in a MySQL update query.  I'm assuming this means that something is the matter with the array I'm sending from the previous page.  The code I'm using on that page is here:

```
<form action="testing.php" method="post">
<input type="hidden" name="job_ids[]" value="

<?php
$senditbaby=0;

while ($senditbaby < $num)                      
{
$senditbabyID=mysql_result($result,$senditbaby,"job_id");                       
echo $senditbabyID;                     
$senditbaby++;
}

?>
">

<div class="modal-footer">
<input type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" value="Approve all tickets">
</div></form>
```

Your help is greatly appreciated!

Comment: You need http://php.net/manual/en/function.str-split.php not implode

Comment: *first* build the value in a variable, *then* do the output. That allows you to debug the variable *before* you output it. - And the mistake is simple: You're just missing to add a comma.

Comment: off topic but important: Firstly, the `mysql_xxx()` functions are deprecated; code should be changed to use `mysqli_xx()` or `PDO` instead. Secondly, please make sure that the IDs being passed to the query are sanitised. If you don't properly escape them, you run a severe risk of your site being hacked by a SQL injection attack.

Answer (score 1):

The is only one `job_ids[]` input, so there is only one value in `$_POST['job_ids']`. Therefore there is nothing to implode. Your loop where you create the value for `job_ids[]` is just echoing out the values on after another, not splitting them up in any manner.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
$variable = implode(',', str_split($_POST['job_ids'], 4));
echo $variable
```

Answer (score 1):

You have really written a long question for a simple mistake: You missed to output the commas, so there aren't any.

However my advice is: First collect the data, then care about the output:

```
function get_job_ids_array($num, $result)
{
    $ids = array();
    $senditbaby = 0;

    while ($senditbaby < $num)                      
    {
         $senditbabyID = mysql_result($result, $senditbaby, "job_id");
         $ids[] = $senditbabyID;
         $senditbaby++;
    }

    return $ids;
}
```

And to get the comma separated list:

```
echo implode(', ', get_job_ids_array($num, $result));
```

Answer (score 0):

When you decode your input manually, it is indeed "2210222022362244", without any seperators. So there is no way to tell your numbers appart from each other in the input. If every number is four digits long, you need to write specific code for that fact, as that is nothing php can guess.

Additionally, php treats $_POST['job_ids'] as a String, you would need to first explode it into an array. This is simply because there is no concept of directly transporting arrays over HTTP.

Perhaps just an error in the example: you use $_POST, but the example url uses GET, so you would actually need $_GET['job_ids']

Answer (score 0):

You can use [GROUP_CONCAT](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/group-by-functions.html#function_group-concat) to get the comma separated job_ids in a single query. This way can be helpful to avoid implode and multiple query.